# Adding new nodes with same name with a loop in xml file but it override first node

Tags: c#, xml

my XML file structure is

```
<Invoices>
  <Invoice>
    <Date>1-1-1</Date>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Items></Items>
    <Total>1</Total>
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

i want to add child node to 
new node  is

```
<Item>
 <Model>1</Model>
 <Quantity>1</Quantity>
 <ItemPrice>1</ItemPrice>
</Item>
```

i want to add this node several times (items may contain several item nodes) 
i put it in loop code here :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
        {

            Model.InnerText = n[i, 0].ToString() ;
            Quantity.InnerText = n[i, 1].ToString();
            ItemPrice.InnerText = n[i, 2].ToString();

            Item.AppendChild(Model);
            Item.AppendChild(Quantity);
            Item.AppendChild(ItemPrice);

            Items.AppendChild(Item);
        }
```

consider i = 3  the output is a single node  not a three child nodes 
can u help please .....

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that with [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
// or with XPath: xdoc.XPathSelectElement("Invoices/Invoice/Items");
XElement items = xdoc.Root.Element("Invoice").Element("Items");

for(int i = 0; i < (dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
{
    var item = new XElement("Item",
                  new XElement("Model", n[i, 0]),
                  new XElement("Quantity", n[i, 1]),
                  new XElement("ItemPrice", n[i, 2]));
    items.Add(item);
}

xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Or even without loop:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
xdoc.Root.Element("Invoice").Element("Items")
    .Add(Enumerable.Range(0, dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1)
                   .Select(i => new XElement("Item",
                                    new XElement("Model", n[i, 0]),
                                    new XElement("Quantity", n[i, 1]),
                                    new XElement("ItemPrice", n[i, 2]))));
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

If you want to add items to last invoice:

```
XElement invoice = xdoc.Root.Elements("Invoice").LastOrDefault();
if (invoice == null)
{
    // throw exception or create and add new Invoice element
}

XElement items = invoice.Element("Items");
if (items == null)
{
    // throw exception or create and add new Items element
}

// create and add Item elements to items, as described above
```

Comment: but it has been added to firs node in file i want it in last node ??

Comment: @user3103176 you have sever `Invoice` elements and want to add new items to last one?

Comment: @user3103176 then use `XElement items = xdoc.Root.Elements("Invoice").Last().Element("Items");` to get items element from last invoice (keep in mind, that requires both `Invoice` and `Items` exist in file

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)



it needs a library right ?

Comment: @user3103176 add `System.Linq` namespace reference to your file. Last and LastOrDefault extensions declared there